# Extending time for application pool recycle process

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

Is there a way to configure the amount of time allocated to IIS to restart an application pool?

I'm dealing with a problem with an in house written module using the Sitecore CMS on IIS.

It looks like the recent update MS013-004 (specifically KB2742601) is causing problems when our application pool recycles. We are receiving

```
ISAPI 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll' reported itself as unhealthy for the following reason: 'Deadlock detected'.
```

As far as I can tell the issue clears up on its own and if the start application pool button in the IIS manager is pressed a little later it will start with no problems.

My guess is that a timeout threshold is passing for the application pool to stop after which time the restart fails as it is already started. That is a pretty important update and I'd rather not need to uninstall.

Note that I'm not looking for how to change the window that the app pool recycles on from the default 20 minutes. We worked around the issue by disabling recycling for the time being  and have the exact schedule desired when things are working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching it turns out that this error can be mitigated  - if not the underlying cause eliminated - by shortening the 'shutdown time limit' on the application pool to one second.

That has allowed the application pools to be stopped and started in a timely fashion and the recycle functions to work as intended. We're working with the vendor to see what we can do about whatever is causing the requests to hang in the app pool but at least things are working.